# Relational Algebra: How does ∞ work?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Getting through some practice exam papers but in regards to the relational algebra I'm confused as to how the infinity symbol (∞) works in this example:

```
π(pname(σ sid=123(Catalogue) ∞ Parts)
```

Where pname is from the Parts entity and sid is from the Catalogue entity. Now, I believe this is selecting the pname from Parts where the sid in Catalogue = 123.

Assuming I'm right, what the hell does ∞ mean here? It's not a join, is it? If I was to write the query version, would I have to use a join?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a [⋈](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28relational_algebra%29#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29)?

Comment: I thought that but it's definitely ∞, there's like three or four questions that all use it. I've never come across it before in databases.

Comment: Maybe it's just because the examiner doesn't know how to type "⋈"? e.g. some people uses φ meaning ∅ and <, > meaning ⟨, ⟩, etc.

Comment: It does look like the join symbol and from the context, joining a part to a catalog, it seems to be the correct conclusion.

Comment: Is the `⋈` symbol used anywhere in that practise papers? If not, then KennyTM and Steve are most probably right.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was really struggling with it, seems so odd that they'd use it, I checked and there's no explanation for why they used that symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. There is no such symbol in relational algebra.